# Google Pay API for OCR/Card Scanning

Tags: android, kotlin, payment

Has anyone integrated google pay api OCR in the android application.
https://developers.google.com/pay/payment-card-recognition/debit-credit-card-recognition

Also can I just use OCR feature from the API without using any other payment features.
Any help is appreciated